# What's the relation between quadratic growth and convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, hessian-matrix

We define quadratic growth as $f(x)-f(x_p)\ge \frac{\mu}{2}\|x-x_p\|^2$, where $x_p$ is the minimizer. I want to know what's the relation between $f$ is quadratic growth and $f$ is convex.

Comment: They are different properties.  $f_1(x)=x^2$ has both, $f_2(x)=x^2+2-2\cos(2x)$ has quadratic growth in your definition since $f_2(x)\ge f_1(x)$ but is not convex, $f_3(x)=|x|^{3/2}$ is convex but does not have quadratic growth as it does not grow fast enough